# Al enviar datos por post no se muestra nada en el html

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo un input dinámico que al clickar en el + se aumentan los campos y al pulsar en la x se eliminan, esa función esta por ajax al enviar esos datos quiero que se envíen a un archivo php que procesara los datos insertándolos en la base de datos y luego mostrar un mensaje si se han insertado correctamente, como yo lo tengo al pulsar en el botón para que los envié se envían pero no muestra el mensaje

```html
<div class="">
  <form name="insertarJugadores" id="insertarJugadores">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="cabecera bg-success text-light p-1">
        <h3 class="ms-3 ">Insertar nombres de los jugadores</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table" id="dynamic_field">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Pulse en el + para introducir jugadores" class="form-control name_list input-group-lg" disabled />
            </td>
            <!-- boton que añade un nuevo campo para introducir valores -->
            <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">+</button></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer btnFooter d-flex justify-content-between">
      <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-md pull-left disabled-control" type="button" id="previous">Anterior</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-success nextBtn btn-md pull-right" id="next" type="button">Siguiente</button> -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-md close" onclick="redireccionamiento('../php/inde.php')">Cerrar</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" id="submit">Reservar</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
<!-- div.btnCaja>div.btnCaja-fila>div.btnCaja-step>a[href="#caja-1"][type="button"].start-class>p{Insertar jugadores} -->
<div id="mostrar_mensaje">0</div>
```

```html
<?php
require_once('../conexion/conexion.php');
require_once('../php/funciones/funciones.php');
//  if(isset($_REQUEST["name"]))

$recibe = $_POST;
echo json_encode($recibe);
?>
```

```html
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var i =1;
        // cuando cliquemos en el boton + se ejecutara la funcion que añade un nuevo campo
        $('#add').click(function() {
            // condicion que puede crear hasta un maximo de 4 campos 
            if (i < 4) return
            var crearTablas = $(
                '<tr id="row' + i + '">' +
                '<td>' +
                '<input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Nombre Jugador" class="form-control name_list"  maxlength="100"/>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                '<button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button>' +
                '</td>' +
                ' </tr>');
               
            $('#dynamic_field').append(crearTablas);
            i++;
            
            
        });
        // creamos la funcion eliminar el boton que consiste en cuando hagamos click en el boton este elimine el campo 
        $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
            // guardamos el identificador del boton en la variable
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
            // eliminamos la fila por medio del identificador y el campo por medio de la variable que contiene el campo, y llamamos a la funcion remove que lo elimina
            $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
            // luego ponemos el contador a 1 para resetear el contador
            i = 1;
        });
       
        $('#submit').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "procesoInsertar.php",
                method: "POST",
                 data:// $('#insertarJugadores').serialize(),
                {
                  name: $('#insertarJugadores').serialize(),
                },
                success: function() {
                    alert(data);
                    // $('#mostrar_mensaje').html(data);
                    $('#insertarJugadores')[0].reset();
                }
            });
        });
       
    });
```

Esto es lo que se muestra al pulsar el boton de reserva

insertar.php?name%5B%5D=hfghgffghhfg&name%5B%5D+name=wssssss&submit=

Comment: Fijate que intentas acceder por **POST** aqui ```$recibe = $_POST;```, en cambio tu formulario no tiene el atributo ```method="POST"```, si no pones el metodo a tu formulario este por defecto va usar el metodo **GET**

Answer (score 0):

creo que estas haciendo mal a la hora de recoger los datos por POST. Yo creo recordad que se hacia de la siguiente manera, por lo que he podido ver en proyectos míos antiguos.

```
// Takes raw data from the request
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

// Converts it into a PHP object
$data = json_decode($json);
```

De esta manera el file_get_contents te coge el valor que te llega del post, vaya lo que seria el data del ajax, después con el json_decode lo desrealiza y tienes el objeto en PHP.

Comment: nada sigue igual

Answer (score 0):

El problema principal es que se te olvido añadir el atributo `method= "POST"` a tu formulario, si no se pone, este por defecto será **GET**

Es también importante añadir la librería jQuery que a veces se nos olvida .

```
<head>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
</head>
```

Use tu código reducido para probar la parte de enviar el formulario con los jugadores en Localhost.

**Ejemplo completo**

*Formulario*

```
<form id="insertarJugadores" method="POST">    
    <h3>Insertar nombres de los jugadores</h3>
    <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="introducir jugadores" />               
    <button type="submit">Reservar</button>   
</form>

<div id="mostrar_mensaje"><!-- RESPONSE AJAX --></div>
```

*Jquery* 
aquí hice pequeños cambios respecto a tu código.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){   
     
    // Tus funciones
    //
    // cuando cliquemos en el boton +, etc...
    // /////////////////////////////////////////

    // Cuando damos click en el formulario
    $(document).on('submit', '#insertarJugadores', function(e) { 
        // Evitar que se recarge la pagina  
        e.preventDefault();

        //Obtenemos datos formulario.
        let data = $(this).serialize(); 
        // Ajax
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  'procesoInsertar.php',
            data: data,
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            $('#mostrar_mensaje').html(data).fadeIn();
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert('Hubo problemas con el formulario')
        });    
    });               
});
</script>
```

*procesoInsertar.php*

```
<?php 
// Reseteo
$jugador = $msg = '';
// Metodo POST existe
if ( isset($_POST) ) :
    // Obtenemos a los jugadores, en caso vacio cerra un array []
    $nmb_jugador = $_POST['name'] ?? [];

    // No existe jugador
    if ($nmb_jugador[0] == ''):
        $msg = 'No existe jugador';
    else :
        // Si deseas usar JSON
        //$jugador = json_encode($nmb_jugador);

        // Como quieres recibir un array de jugadores debemos recorrlo para asi mostrar los nombres existentes
        foreach ($nmb_jugador as $j) :
            // Aqui tambien podrias insertar los jugadores a la BD
            //
            // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
            
            // Mayuscula primera letra
            $j = ucfirst($j);
            // Concatenamos judadores
            $jugador .= "Jugador: $j<br>";
        endforeach;
        
    endif;
endif;

// Retornar respuesta AJAX
// Error
if (isset($msg)) echo $msg;
// Success, mostramos jugadores 
if (isset($jugador)) echo $jugador;
```

Probarlo para que veas que funcione, y ya intentas implementarlo con las funciones de añadir jugador etc.